# ssh ProxyCommand fording port from 2nd to third?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, squid

I set up a Proxy command to get to a test box I'm working on that is acting like a host and is not connected to the internet. The set up is accessible from my home from one of my new Raspberry Pi 3 with a built-in wifi that I dedicate to connecting to the test box and it's private network.

If I need to connect to that machine from another computer (other than the raspberry pi 3) I can do so using host hopping with a ProxyCommand in my ssh config on the given machine. e.g.:

```
host testbox
    Hostname 10.10.1.1
    Port 2222
    User myuser
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ProxyCommand ssh rpithree nc %h %p
```

Here's the question. Since the testbox is not connected to the internet, I set up a squid server on the raspberry pi that I can use through a port tunnel when connecting directly from the Pi 3 to the testbox or vice versa. I know I can run ssh -N with the port forwarding and background it with nohup, but since I'm hopping through that pi 3 anyway, I was wondering if there was some way to modify the proxy command so that it picks up port 3128 on the way through and forwards it as needed?

Comment: as an added comment, I have the squid set up to only listen to localhost since I only installed/run it for the testbox to use. So I can't simply forward 'hostname' from one of the other boxes on my network.

Comment: btw, I also know I can open just that address to squid and have been doing that in the meantime to save time, but I do lots of things like that and would still like to know if forwarding (including other ports/services) mid-hop like that is possible.